# React.js - TODO List striking through task text and sorting not working

Tags: reactjs

I am having  a hard time with a React.js project. I have a TODO list and there is a function to mark a task as done. I have a button next to each and every task and if I click on it the following function will be called.

```
crossLine(key){
    const currentTaskArray = [...this.state.task]

    const deletedItems = currentTaskArray.filter(deletedItem => deletedItem.key == key);
    const taskAfterDeleted = currentTaskArray.filter(deletedTask => deletedTask.key !== key);
    this.setState({
        task: [taskAfterDeleted,deletedItems]
    })
};
```

I first need to strike this item ( just html strikethrough) so that I know it is done. After that, it should be removed from the array and should be moved to the bottom of the list and the rest of the items should be moved accordingly. The following function does not seem to contain anything inside deletedItems.

you can find the full project at https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-gauss-s12bf.

Comment: You have tried to use the `===` and not `==`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.filter()` returns an array of the remaining elements. Therefore, `taskAfterDeleted` and `deletedItems` are both arrays. You'll need to spread them in your new state:

`[...taskAfterDeleted, ...deletedItems]`